# Generating an AD token in C#

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, token

I am trying generate an Azure AD token but i am getting an error with the following;

```
    var authParam = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
```

The error is;

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'customWebUI' of 'PlatformParameters.PlatformParameters(PromptBehabior, ICustomWebUi)

I have tried adding;

```
    var authParam = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, true);
```

But with that i get;

cannot convert from 'bool' to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Extensibility.ICustomWebUi'

I am missing something?

Comment: seems that the second parameter is not a boolean but Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Extensibility.ICustomWebUi

Comment: can you share the full code / link you've followed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were using .NET Core framework, but referred to a .net framework sample.

With .NET Core framework, I will encounter the same error as yours.

[image]

With .NET Framework, it just works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to implement this in .NET Core though?

Comment: Tony - your answer is not helpful at all.  If we wanted to use .NET Framework I'd use .NET Framework.  Sounds like your documentation needs updating.